# How to get current value using onDoubleClick event listener on PrimeReact Listbox

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm trying to get current value using onDoubleClick event listener on PrimeReact Listbox to use it for updating data on the list.

I set `e.target.ariaLabel` as arg, but it doesn't work.

The error says, `'Property 'ariaLabel' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.'`.

Then I triggered the event, checked console and found `ariaLabel` surely exists, which is quite confusing.

How can I get current value properly?
Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
// initialize the state
  const [selectedSubClassification, setSelectedSubClassification] = useState<{ id: number; name: string }>({
    id: 0,
    name: '',
  });

// trigger the event
onDoubleClick={(e) => {
 setSelectedSubClassification(e.target.ariaLabel)
 }}

// call func
  function addDataFromList() {
    if (data[selectedRow.row]['name']) {
      let prevData: any = [...data];
      prevData = prevData.map((item, index) => {
        if (index === selectedRow.row) {
          return {
            ...item,
            mst_main_classification: selectedMainClassification.name,
            mst_main_classification_id: selectedMainClassification.id,
            mst_sub_classification: selectedSubClassification.name,
        mst_
sub_classification_id: selectedSubClassification.id,
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
      setData(prevData);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```xml
      <ListBox
        value={selectedCity}
        options={cities}
        optionLabel="name"
        onDoubleClick={(e) => alert(e.target.ariaLabel)}
      />
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-paeglr?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.


I tried your suggestion, but it seems it still doesn't work. 
I updated my question above with the code you suggested.


I checked console and e.target.ariaLabel surely exists (I attached image file above) and the data that I'm looking for is there. But yet 'Property 'ariaLabel' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.' error is returned...

Comment: That is just a TypeScript warning but the propery is there.  Just add `//@ts-ignore` to it.